# Set Page Title Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

In the source code of a WordPress plugin called *Advanced Ajax Page Loader*, I see the author using code like this to set the page title after ajax succeedes:

```
data = data.split('<title>')[1];
titles = data.split('</title>')[0];
jQuery(document).attr('title', (jQuery("<div/>").html(titles).text()));
```

I tried to replace the last line with

```
jQuery(document).attr('title', titles);
```

and the plugin also worked.

So my question is: why he uses  `(jQuery("<div/>").html(titles).text())` instead of simply applying `titles` the variable?

And what does `(jQuery("<div/>")` exactly mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jQuery("<div/>")` creates a div element, see http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2. Here it's used to sanitize the `titles` var.

`jQuery("<div/>").html(titles).text()` creates an empty div (`jQuery("<div/>")`), sets the content to `titles` (`.html(titles)`) and reads the text of this div (`.text()`). HTML tags get read as text, so no HTML/JS can be injected into the document title, only pure text. It's a security feature of this script.

Comment: And why he's not using: `titles = $(data).text();` ??? And then use directly titles instead. I don't get it

Comment: @A.Wolff What if data doesn't contain HTML?

Comment: Ok i see, if user try to inject some HTML/JS, this answer makes sense

Comment: Well, I get it from your edited answer. Many thanks.

Comment: @PaulAllen: No, it's fine. `<div/>` gets expanded to `<div></div>` by jQuery, which is standard HTML.

Comment: I'm wondering do we really need to be so careful with our OWN blogs ╮(╯-╰)╭

Comment: You can never be too careful :)

Answer (score 0):

That is syntax to create a new `div` element.